# How to check user is my friend or not using Fouresquare API in iphone?

Tags: iphone, foursquare

I have integrate Foursquare API for iPhone application.I want to check this particular user is friend or not.

Can you give me advice for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the foursquare documentation: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks for reply I have already read that documents in that document is explain how to send friend request to other user.But I want to check this user is my fried or not.Please give me idea if you know about this.Thanks